# Mounting and dismouting removable volumes changing users

Tags: automount

Computer with 2 or 3 users.

I put a dvd or plug an usb key in the system and everything is OK !

If I change of user, everything becomes out of order even the user is an administrator.

I understand that -maybe- it's due to rights access to removable device but i'm not sure.

Is anybody know how do change user and go on to use DVD reader or USB key without having to reboot the computer ?

Many thanks

Dom